# How to take data from the search in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

1. When making a search query like this:

   blogspot.com/search?q=9999999

   what should I include in the loop to access the result?

   ```
       <b:if cond='data:view.search.query'>         
        <b:loop values='WHAT???' var='post'>

         </b:loop>
       </b:if>
   ```
2. /search?updated-max=2023-04-13T05:47:00-07:00&max-results=7

   How to catch this request?

   ```
   <b:if cond='data:view.search.query'> <-- doesn't work
   ```